# i am using outlook 2016 and window 7 enterprise. Would like to extract attachment automatically

Tags: python, outlook-2016

Current version:outlook 2016 and window 7 enterprise

Have tried the script below, but it did not pull and save the attachment to my path.

However, it works fine when i am using outlook 2010 and Windows 7 Enterprise.

Kindly advise

**Below is my script**

```
 import win32com.client
 import os
 outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

 folder=outlook.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("E News Letters").Folders("DAILY_Subscribe to our newsletters") 

 path01 = os.path.expanduser("D:\\Users\\xxx\Desktop\\Projects")


 messages = folder.Items
 message = messages.GetFirst()


 for m in messages:

        if "DAILY_Subscribe to our newsletters" in str(message):

        try:
        print (message)
        attachments = message.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        print(os.getcwd() + "\\" + str(attachment))
        attachment.SaveASFile(path01 + "\\" + str(attachment)) #Saves to the attachment to current folder
        print (attachment)
        message = messages.GetNext()

    except:
        print (attachment)
    else:

        continue
```